# Upload video in chunks Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I'm receiving file content in chunks. As I've read the latest nuget recommended to work with Azure blob storage is `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, but I'm unable to find any example or method how to upload the file in chunks? Is it supported?

I'm receiving the range as `Range` header. I'm using this [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)

Comment: have you tried using AppendBlob?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The methods you would want to use are [`BlockBlobClient.StageBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) which uploads the chunk data and [`BlockBlobClient.CommitBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.commitblocklist?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlockBlobClient_CommitBlockList_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobHttpHeaders_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Nullable_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_AccessTier__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) which commits the blocks and creates a block blob.

Here's a really crappy implementation of the functionality :). It basically reads a really large file from the local computer and uploads it by splitting the file in 1MB chunks.

```
    static void UploadBlobsInChunks()
    {
        var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "test");
        containerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
        var filePath = @"C:\temp\mymovie.mp4";

        var blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("mymovie.mp4");
        int blockSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB Block
        int offset = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> blockIds = new List<string>();

        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            var bytesRemaining = fs.Length;
            do
            {
                var dataToRead = Math.Min(bytesRemaining, blockSize);
                byte[] data = new byte[dataToRead];
                var dataRead = fs.Read(data, offset, (int) dataToRead);
                bytesRemaining -= dataRead;
                if (dataRead > 0)
                {
                    var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(counter.ToString("d6")));
                    blockBlobClient.StageBlock(blockId, new MemoryStream(data));
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Block {0} uploaded successfully.", counter.ToString("d6")));
                    blockIds.Add(blockId);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            while (bytesRemaining > 0);
            Console.WriteLine("All blocks uploaded. Now committing block list.");
            var headers = new BlobHttpHeaders()
            {
                ContentType = "video/mp4"
            };
            blockBlobClient.CommitBlockList(blockIds, headers);
            Console.WriteLine("Blob uploaded successfully!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, but what if I want to replace the first block of the file later? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible to replace the blocks. However, IIRC there was a bug in SDK with replacing blocks (please search on Github repository for this issue) so please make sure you're not encountering that bug while replacing blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much.
How can I upload file to specific path. Like - (ContainerName/folder1/folder2/file.jpg)

Comment: @MohammedAshrafali just replace the path here `var blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("mymovie.mp4")` with your path. E.g. `var blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("folder1/folder2/file.jpg")`