# How do I use HTTP Chunked file transfers to/from Azure.Storage?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-disk

I'm interested in adding a security front end to AzureStorage for authentication, access control, excessive usage (rate limiter), and other features.

I've [read repos on Github](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/AsyncDynamicZip/tree/core-ziparchive) regarding ASP.NET Core (I'm at 5.0), however during this research I came across many issues regarding HTTP CHUNKED, and do want broad browser support (Desktop and mobile) to simply GET the ASP.NET Core protected front end, and then use that CHUNKED verb to resume downloading from Azure Storage.

How can I use ASP.NET Core to support this feature in supported Web Browsers using Blob or other implementations of Azure Disk?

Comment: What do you mean by "use that CHUNKED verb to resume downloading"?

Comment: Are you asking for help actually implementing chunk uploading to Azure Blob Storage? Or are you wanting some kind of broader advice? I don't know if `HTTP CHUNKED` has any relation to how the Azure Storage .NET Client handles the uploads internally. There are quite a few examples already out there to do this. I can provide a link if you'd like. The `BlockBlobClient` class supports this, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm thinking of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) without much study into web browsers and how they might allow the resumption of a download if a reboot or restart of a browser occurred, saving time and bandwidth

Comment: @jandrew Yes, examples are wanted and appreciated. My thoughts are centered around parity between mirroring what the arbitrary browser/app/code client would want, and acting as a data proxy (in the same datacenter to save costs)  to pull the data, and stream it without fully loading a potentially large zipped/unzipped blob.

Comment: @TLDR Are you wanting to do this from a browser based JS app? Either way, there should be a Azure Storage client library that you can use to do this. Is your concern about compatibility with HTTP/2? I'd have to look into what the client is doing internally to see how it's handling requests. I don't know if it's using the standard Transfer Encoding : Chunked in the process.

Comment: @TLDR It appears the actual HTTP API for the service does use the chunked transfer encoding mechanism when doing this. They do list HTTP /1.1 as the supported version currently for the API. I'm not entirely following your concern regarding acting as a data proxy but hopefully that shines a little light on your question about it.

Comment: Chunked transfer encoding does not enable resumable downloads.  It’s simply an alternative to a content-length header or closing the socket for for a HTTP client to figure out how large the HTTP response body is.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide links to docs and example you can use as a reference. If I understand correctly, you want to look at the `BlockBlobClient` class if you're wanting to upload data in chunks.

Here's a link to the API reference for HTTP level requests. Specifically it's the Put Block request, which is what gets called when doing one of these chunked uploads through the client. You mentioned HTTP CHUNKED, I assume you're referring to the `Transfer Encoding : Chunked` header and the transfer mechanism? It looks like HTTP/1.1 is the supported version for the Azure Blob Storage API.

I'm not entirely clear on your concerns but I know chunked transfers are not supported in HTTP/2. Not sure what you would do about that until the service is updated at some point in the future. You said you were building a front-end, which I assume is likely a JavaScript based application of some sort? If so, you can use the Blob Storage JavaScript client library. Obviously if you're uploading from inside ASP.NET, then use the C# package.

HTTP API Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block

Example : [Upload video in chunks Azure blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481720/upload-video-in-chunks-azure-blob-storage)

Docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet