# HTTP PUT request by content from inputStream with unknown size and can not set ChunkedStreamingMode in HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to send an HTTP PUT request to Azure Blob Storage, but ChunkedStreamingMode is not allowed. I'm reading from InputStream with an unknown size. I can separate the PUT Blob request into multiple PUT Block requests (Azure Blob Storage provides a PUT BLOCK operation that stores the single block and in the end, I can build all the blocks to one Blob). Is it a good solution to buffer by 1 MiB in the memory and send it like a block? Or reading from the inputstream and saving it to a temporary file in the local file system, then reading the file and sending it as Block is a better solution?

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying to use? Looks like the Azure SDK for C# supports chunks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481720/upload-video-in-chunks-azure-blob-storage so should be possible in Java too.

Comment: I'm not using the Azure SDK.

Comment: I suppose the Azure SDK uses the REST API (though I don't really know how it works), so by looking at the Azure SDK's sources you should be able to figure out what they do.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue get resolved? Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: I have implemented it by storing the InputStream in a temporary file. I'm not using the Azure SDK, so I have implemented it by the REST API by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you want to upload a big file by chunk. I think both of your solutions could work and I'll provide some sample code for your second solution: save the input stream as a temp file and upload it by chunk, just try code below by Azure Blob SDK:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.ProgressReceiver;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.AccessTier;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobHttpHeaders;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobRequestConditions;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.ParallelTransferOptions;

public class StorageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //skip the process about saving a temp file, just leaving its path 
        String tempFilePath = "";

        String connString = "<azure storage connection string>";
        String containerName = "<container name>";
        String destBlobName = "<blob name with path>";

        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connString).buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(containerName).getBlobClient(destBlobName);
        // 1MB per request in case of consuming too much jvm memory while uploading
        long blockSize = 1024 * 1024;
        ParallelTransferOptions parallelTransferOptions = new ParallelTransferOptions().setBlockSizeLong(blockSize)
                // 2 Concurrency requests as max,you can set more than it to accelerate uploading
                .setMaxConcurrency(2)
                .setProgressReceiver(new ProgressReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void reportProgress(long bytesTransferred) {
                        System.out.println("uploaded:" + bytesTransferred);
                    }
                });

        BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentLanguage("en-US").setContentType("binary");

        blobClient.uploadFromFile(tempFilePath, parallelTransferOptions, headers, null, AccessTier.HOT,
                new BlobRequestConditions(), Duration.ofMinutes(30));

    }

}
```

I have tested on my side and it works for me to upload a 5GB file.
Let me know if you have any more questions.